# Can we say that $\|e_i a e_i - a\| \to 0\ $?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ be a non-unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Then for any approximate unit $(e_i)_{i \in I}$ and for any $a \in A$ can we say that $\|e_i a e_i - a e_i \| \xrightarrow{i} 0\ $?

Comment: So long as your approximate unit is norm-bounded, we have $$\|e_iae_i-ae_i\|\leq\|e_ia-a\|\|e_i\|\leq M\|e_ia-a\|\to 0.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is true. Following the usual definition of approximate unit in a $C^*$-algebra (where the approximating elements are contractive), we get
$$\|e_i a e_i-ae_i\| =\|(e_i a-a)e_i\| \le \|e_i a-a\|\stackrel{i \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Does the downvoter care to justify their downvote?